# Plot cone using a constraints matrix

Tags: plotting

I have the following constraints matrix and coordinates vectors, respectively:

```
constrm = ({
{3, 5, 6},
{0, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 1},
{1, 1, 1}
 });x = {100, -50, -50, -86.6025, 0, 86.6025}; y = {0, 86.6025, -86.6025, 
50, -100, 50}; z = {0, 0, 0, 200, 200, 200};
```

I would like to plot a cone with centre and radius consistent with the constraints matrix. In particular, if the i-th element of the second row of constrm is equal to 1, then the centre of the cone has the following coordinates {x[[constrm[[1,i]]]],y[[constrm[[1,i]]]],z[[constrm[[1,i]]]]}, otherwise Null.

This is my attempt:

```
For[i = 1, i <= Dimensions[constrm][[2]], i++, 
If[constrm[[2, i]] == 1, 
Graphics3D[{Magenta, 
Cone[{{x[[constrm[[1, i]]]] - 35, y[[constrm[[1, i]]]], 
   z[[constrm[[1, i]]]]}, {x[[constrm[[1, i]]]], 
   y[[constrm[[1, i]]]], z[[constrm[[1, i]]]]}}, 6]}], Null]]
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: I find the solution: 

    Table[If[constrm[[2, i]] == 1, 
    Show@Graphics3D[{Magenta, 
     Cone[{{x[[constrm[[1, i]]]] - 35, y[[constrm[[1, i]]]], 
        z[[constrm[[1, i]]]]}, {x[[constrm[[1, i]]]], 
        y[[constrm[[1, i]]]], z[[constrm[[1, i]]]]}}, 4]}], 
     Graphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 0]]], {i, 3}]

Answer (score 1):

```
indices = Pick[constrm[[1]], constrm[[2]], 1];

coords = Transpose[{x, y, z}][[indices]];

Graphics3D[{Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 0],
  Magenta, Cone[{# - {35, 0, 0}, #}, 4]} & /@ coords]
```

[image]

or, combine all steps:

```
f = Graphics3D[{Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 0], Magenta, 
     Cone[{# - {35, 0, 0}, #}, 4]} & /@ 
       Pick[Transpose[#2][[#[[1]]]], #[[2]], 1]] &;

f[constrm, {x, y, z}]
```

> same picture